# i have an error on IS PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “IS”

Tags: plsql

```
create or replace procedure seqn (sname IN seq.seqname%type , 

startv IN seq.startval%type , 

incby IN seq.incrementby%type ,

 maxi IN seq.maxilimit%type );

     IS
s_count integer ;

    begin
    select count(*)
    into s_count
     from sequence;
     where seqname := sname ;
if s_count := 0
then
    insert into seq
    values(sname,startv,incby,maxi);
end if;

    end seqn ;
    /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found four errors in your procedure.

Firstly, remove the two semicolons from the end of the following lines:

```
 maxi IN seq.maxilimit%type );
```

```sql
     from sequence;
```

Secondly, don't use `:=` for comparing values in the following two lines, use `=` instead.

```
     where seqname := sname ;
if s_count := 0
```